# json request - no line breaks in div

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, line-breaks

i save data in a data base with json/jquery/ajax.
When i load the data in a textarea i get the result which i want to have.
But when i load the data in a DIV, then there are no line breaks.
I tested everything with css including

```
white-space:pre;
```

etc.

I'm saving the data in json with

```
"', 'text': '" + $('#textInput').val() +
```

but I've also tested it with .html() and .text().

Reading the data:

```
$('#textOutput').text(data.d.Text);
```

I'm getting the corect text in my div, but there are no line breaks!

CSS of textOutput

```
.textOutput // <div> not working, <textarea> working
{
width:100%;
border: 0;
height: auto;
overflow:visible; // also tested with auto etc.
margin: 5px 8px 5px 0px;
font-family: Courier New, Courier;
font-size: 12px;
// white-space:pre;
}
```

CSS of input is equivalent

Comment: what are you using for your database? php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using PHP, you have to do a `nl2br()` call to change the `\n\r` to a `<br />` tag. You can also do this in Javascript by `data.d.Text.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");`

For ASP you can use `.Replace("\n", "<br />")`.

Comment: this is what you need, but the alternative for asp.net

Comment: it's working - thanks!
(answer can/will be accepted in 3 mins)